# Regex to match string between opening and closing parenthesises, but not if there is a specific word after opening parenthesis

Tags: regex

As per title, I'm trying to perform a regex to match strings between an opening and closing parenthesis, however if the word "SELECT" is directly after the opening parenthesis then I do not want the string to match.

Here's a sample string:

```
WITH test AS (
    SELECT
        DATE_DIFF(start_date, end_date, DAY),
        DATE_DIFF(start_date
                  ,end_date
                  ,DAY)
    FROM apple
)
,test 2 AS (
    SELECT blah
    FROM blah
)
SELECT
    *
FROM test
```

At the moment, I am using the following regex `(\()(.|\n)*(\))`, which will give me the following match (< indicates start of match, > indicates end of match)

```
WITH test AS <(
    SELECT
        DATE_DIFF(start_date, end_date, DAY),
        DATE_DIFF(start_date
                  ,end_date
                  ,DAY)
    FROM apple
)
,test 2 AS (
    SELECT blah
    FROM blah
)>
SELECT
    *
FROM test
```

What I am looking for is actually this:

```
WITH test AS (
    SELECT
        DATE_DIFF<(start_date, end_date, DAY)>,
        DATE_DIFF<(start_date
                  ,end_date
                  ,DAY)>
    FROM apple
)
,test 2 AS (
    SELECT blah
    FROM blah
)
SELECT
    *
FROM test
```

I am unsure how to add an exception expression to the regex pattern I am using

EDIT: here's a regex builder showing the problem better: [regexr.com/6in0s](https://regexr.com/6in0s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\((?!\s*SELECT\b)[^()]*\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wj70iA/1).

*Details*:

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?!\s*SELECT\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are zero or more whitspaces followed with a whole word `SELECT` immediately to the right of the current location
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.